# VBA: copy range of data across workbooks and "save as" function in loop

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I want to copy a range of cells in my .csv file into a template.csv (named "pp"). Then I would like to save the template as "name of the original .csv file_2", without closing the original template as I would need it to do this procedure in loop for all the files in my folder. I have come up with this code that doesn't work:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim pp As Workbook      ' Workbook to receive the copied data
Dim ppSht As Worksheet  ' Worksheet where copied data will be inserted
Dim Wkb As Workbook     ' Temporary workbook for the Loop
Dim Sht As Worksheet    ' Temporary worksheet variable for the loop

MyFile = Dir("R:\COMT study\Silvia\Cognitive data\COMT 1\Tasks\CPT*.csv*")

Set pp = Workbooks("pp.csv")
Set ppSht = pp.Sheets("Sheet1")

Do While MyFile <> ""
Set Wkb = Workbook.Open("R:\COMT study\Silvia\Cognitive data\COMT 1\Tasks\CPT" & MyFile)
Set Sht = Wkb.Worksheets("sheet1")
Sht.Range("A1:G113").Copy

With ppSht
.Range("A1:G113").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End With

pp.SaveCopyAs Filename = MyFile_2.csv

Wkb.Close True

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

I am new to the vba coding and I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I don't get any error messages, the code simply doesn't run. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to recommend you how to use a CSV file (Comma-separated values). By this a csv file does not have any sheets. Therefore you can reach the worksheet with the following, there `wb` is the workbook. Another good advice is to use `Option Explicit` that enables some error codes, example if you get to initialize a variable.
    Dim pp As Workbook
    pp.Worksheets (1)

```
Do While MyFile <> ""
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("R:\COMT study\Silvia\Cognitive data\COMT 1\Tasks\CPT" & MyFile)
With wb.Worksheets(1)
    Range(A1,G113).copy
End With
With ppSht
    .Range(A1,G113).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End With

pp.SaveCopyAs Filename = "MyFile_2.csv"
'Remove the wb.Close if you want the sheet to stay open (Not recommended if there are many files)
wb.Close
MyFile = Dir
loop
```

Try using some of this (Haven't tried it so just use it as a template). See if you can get any errors or at least if you can collect the data from the file into a array.